# How to copy a list over in python without keeping them linked?

Tags: python, list, numpy, vector

I tried:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = A
B[0] = A[0]*3
```

should give:

```
B == [3,2,3]
True
A == [1,2,3]
True
```

but what it really does:

```
B == [3,2,3]
A == [3,2,3]
```

how do I copy A over in B without keeping A linked to B?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `B = A[:]` instead of `B = A`? This makes a shallow copy.

Comment: you can do B = A.copy() returns a shallow copy

Comment: you can use this too B = [x for x in A]

Comment: Why did you tag this NumPy? You only talk about lists in this question. If you *are* using NumPy, keep in mind that NumPy arrays are **not lists** and do not behave like lists. `A[:]` won't copy a NumPy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are only pointing the reference to B, without making a copy at all. Instead do the following to actually create a copy.

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = A[:]
```

This will work if there are no referenced variables. If you don't want that behaviour, then use a deep_copy method as below

```
B = copy.deepcopy(A)
```

Then if you change A, it won't change B

Comment: No, the OP does not make a copy at all: `B` and `A` refer to the **same** list. One can solve it by making a shallow copy.

Comment: Thank you - I have modified it. Apologies for the original error